# How do I kill Namir?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

So I made a pretty big mistake.* No need wallowing over it, I'm here now.

Point is, I'm at the third boss in Deux Ex: Human Revolution, and I lost all my augmentations. Basically, I have a permanent EMP. This puts me at a severe disadvantage.

Can I still kill him? How do I do it?

(I have a few weapons, but nothing interesting. I'm working mostly with what I can pick up around me, which is hard with my vision impaired like this.)

---

*Huge spoilers below here. Do **not** read this unless you are already in Singapore. You have been warned.

> Basically, if you followed Prittchard's advice and went to a LIMB clinic to get your biochip replaced, you've pretty much given the antagonist a kill-switch. Prior to the boss-fight, she activates it and puts you in a constant EMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have a handy supply of frag mines.

The way I beat him was to stick around the outside ring until he became visible and tried to chuck some grenades at me.  Then I'd run around the corner and drop a frag mine midway to the next corner.  He'll often chase me and then take a hit from the mine.  Just be really careful to avoid that frag mine if it ends up not being triggered (run through the inside ring instead).

Once I ran out of frag mines, I started using concussion mines to stun him for a few seconds, which let me snipe him a few times.

Always keep moving as he'll jump over some walls to get at you if you start camping in one corner.  You do not want to be up close and personal with his plasma gun.  I pretty much spent the entire fight running from one outside corner of the room to the other.

The same tactics can be used without augs, but he'll be harder to spot and react to without the see through walls aug.

Comment: I knew I should've stocked up on mines. >.<

Comment: Having a pistol with the armor piercing upgrade makes this battle relatively easy (with it's high rate of fire, mobility and the damage you can deal with it).  Just throw some mines nearby to find out where he is and start firing.

Answer (score 12):

This is EASY, even on Deus Ex mode. If you got the software "upgrade" and have no frags, this can be done in under a minute.

1. Equip the laser rifle (if you don't have one, you can pick up multiple of them in the preceding base).  You'll need at least 2 full batteries, again which you can get in the base.
2. Fire from behind cover.  Because the laser rifle is recoil free unlike most other weapons, you don't suffer the wild inaccuracy with the laser rifle.
3. Sweep with the laser to reveal him from cloak, and when he appears just focus the bead on him.  Since you're firing behind cover and he doesn't use it, he won't even get a shot off with the plasma rifle.
4. If he throws a grenade, just sprint to a safe position where you can repeat the process from.
5. It takes about 2 full clips of laser rifle to drop him.  Easy.

Comment: If you can use Smart Vision, the laser rifle is even deadlier. Keep  just one wall between you and him and you should be close enough to fire straight into his head through the cover. He even slows down when he's taking damage.

Comment: This can be combined with the answer Pwopa Grrl gave - maybe overkill, but that's how I managed to get past this fight.

Answer (score 5):

The best, easiest, most amusingly obvious way is

Before going up the elevator, hack into the closest security mainframe that controls a turret. If you have the "Carry heavy objects" Aug, you can pick up the turret, and bring it with you into the elevator.

Just ride up with the turret, push it as far out of the doorway as possible, and trigger the boss. Then, when the scene completes, run back behind the turret, and wait.

Be careful, though, because and EMP grenade can take out your little buddy, so alternatively, you could run around the boss area and force Jaron into the sight of the turret. The turret, once it gets into steady fire, prevents him from shooting or doing anything until he's dead.

Comment: I also activated my target seeking combat rifle modification before the cut scene and that seemed to still work while under the effects of the chip malfunction.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - no augmentations, and had to defeat this boss. I noticed that I was able to use some of my augmentations, but there was no UI indications that they were on. For example, I have the augmentation that allows me to see NPCs through walls. Even under the effects of the EMP, I could turn this on and it would work. However I would have no idea how much battery power I had left, so I just had to wing it. If my batteries were empty, the "no energy" warning did appear, so there is that at least.

Also...there is another way. I'd call this an exploit, so I'm not condoning its use, but just in case you get too frustrated...

My first attempt at defeating this guy ended in my death (as expected). My previous save was before the cut scene, so I skipped it since I didn't need to see it again. Low and behold, I still have all my augmentations and there was no EMP. I didn't defeat the boss this way, but it sure was tempting. :)

Comment: That's definitely a bug. When I skip the cut scene, I am still EMPed.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I never tried it a second time - maybe I just got lucky.

Answer (score 2):

There's a really simple way to do this; just use a takedown as he's scaling a wall.

See this video for a walkthrough: [Deus Ex Human Revolution - Bossfight Jaron Namir (Highest Difficulty)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snApInyxT9s)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you took the new biochip. :(

Answer (score 1):

I brought the turret from downstairs up with me, left it in front of the elevator doors, triggered the cut-scene, and ran back to the elevator. Perhaps that's the "exploit" mentioned by @Adeese.

Answer (score 1):

Just got him now. Put a frag mine in the middle room, and start running in the outer one and don't stop until you hear your mine blowing. After that I finished him off with a grenade launcher but I guess you could use something else.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the chip upgrade but I don't think it would have mattered if I had.  I had the grenade launcher, and I just blasted 3/4 grenades and was done (simplest boss fight ever). This was on Deus Ex difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

During my first playthrough I killed Namir after taking the LIMB upgrade, it was a painful experience with all those flashing colours.

Anyway, the way that I did this was if you remember before the boss there is a turret out in the court yard, I simply carried this into the lift with me, after reprogramming it to attack enemies. If you drop it as you walk out of the lift it survives the cut scene and will attack Namir.

Namir will also attack it back, but while he's targeting the turret you can get some very well aimed headshots off.

Answer (score 0):

I actually also got that new biochip and thus had to fight him with the augmentations being crippled. The way I got him down was using my combat rifle and just use the four corners of the entire room. You easily see him aproaching, jumping over the wall, you then unload half a clip in him and run away when he tosses the grenades or shoots the plasma weapon at you. And then you simply repeat this.

Answer (score 0):

I had no augmentations either, as a result of the chip upgrade, so I ran around the room shooting him with a shotgun until he died.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adeese mentioned, your augs still have some functionality even with the "upgraded" chip. They were not available straight away, so I think maybe your cells start empty and recharge very slowly. Anyway after a certain period of time of firing from cover and running away, I was able to use the Typhoon which finished off Namir quite quickly.